# Could not list layers for this store error when creating new ImageMosaic

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

When I try to [save a new imagemosaic store](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) I get the following error:

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving
>   them: Failed to create reader from
>   file:///home/jswitzer/postgis_rasters and hints null

In my postgis database a new table does get auto created with the following ddl:

```
create TABLE postgis_rasters (
    fid integer not null default nextval('postgis_rasters_fid_seq'::regclass),
    the_geom geometry(Polygon,4269),
    location varchar(255),
    ingestion timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (fid)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX postgis_rasters_pkey ON postgis_rasters (fid);
CREATE INDEX spatial_postgis_rasters_the_geom ON postgis_rasters (the_geom);
```

Here are the contents of /home/jswitzer/postgis_rasters

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer      167 Nov 23 15:10 datastore.properties
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer      161 Nov 23 15:14 indexer.properties
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150101.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150102.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150103.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150104.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150105.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150106.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150107.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150108.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150109.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150110.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150111.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150112.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150113.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150114.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer 25621641 Nov 23 15:17 rtma_tmax_20150115.tif
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root     root            4 Nov 23 15:43 sample_image
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jswitzer jswitzer       15 Nov 23 15:15 timeregex.properties
```

datastore.properties:

```
SPI=org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisNGDataStoreFactory
host=localhost
port=*****
database=****
schema=public
user=*****
passwd=*****
preparedStatements=true
```

indexer.properties:

```
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
```

timeregex.properties:

```
regex=[0-9]{8}
```

geoserver log:

```
2015-11-23 15:43:40,266 WARN [gce.imagemosaic] - Unable to close indexing(none): (none): Name or service not known
java.lang.RuntimeException: (none): (none): Name or service not known
        at javax.media.jai.remote.SerializableRenderedImage.<init>(SerializableRenderedImage.java:567)
        at javax.media.jai.remote.SerializableRenderedImage.<init>(SerializableRenderedImage.java:454)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.storeSampleImage(Utils.java:953)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.createSampleImage(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:469)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.indexingPostamble(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:412)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker$MosaicDirectoryWalker.<init>(ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.java:132)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.run(ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.java:196)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.createMosaic(Utils.java:359)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.checkSource(Utils.java:1237)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.initReaderFromURL(ImageMosaicReader.java:516)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.<init>(ImageMosaicReader.java:468)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicFormat.java:483)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicFormat.java:103)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1441)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1369)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:59)
...
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-23 15:43:40,271 ERROR [imagemosaic.Utils] - (none): (none): Name or service not known
java.lang.RuntimeException: (none): (none): Name or service not known
        at javax.media.jai.remote.SerializableRenderedImage.<init>(SerializableRenderedImage.java:567)
        at javax.media.jai.remote.SerializableRenderedImage.<init>(SerializableRenderedImage.java:454)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.storeSampleImage(Utils.java:953)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.createSampleImage(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:469)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicConfigHandler.indexingPostamble(ImageMosaicConfigHandler.java:412)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker$MosaicDirectoryWalker.<init>(ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.java:132)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.run(ImageMosaicDirectoryWalker.java:196)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.createMosaic(Utils.java:359)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.Utils.checkSource(Utils.java:1237)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.initReaderFromURL(ImageMosaicReader.java:516)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.<init>(ImageMosaicReader.java:468)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicFormat.java:483)
        at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicFormat.java:103)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1441)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1369)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-23 15:43:40,276 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:///home/jswitzer/postgis_rasters
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:///home/jswitzer/postgis_rasters and hints null
        at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:151)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:59)
        at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.fullSize(GeoServerDataProvider.java:242)
        at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.updateMatched(GeoServerTablePanel.java:566)
        at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:559)
        at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:171)
        at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:96)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$1.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:106)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:106)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSuccessfulSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:79)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:70)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractCoverageStorePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractCoverageStorePage.java:116)
...
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:///home/jswitzer/postgis_rasters and hints null
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1443)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1369)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:146)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
        at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:90)
        ... 119 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. In the following line of geoserver.log's stacktrace, (none) is referring to the hostname which wasn't set

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: (none): (none): Name or service not known
```

To resolve the issue I edited /etc/hostname to have a hostname and /etc/hosts to resolve the hostname to an IP. Then I rebooted the box and adding the image mosaic store worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the owner permission of the folder I tried to add that was causing the error. GeoServer is running on tomcat so I changed user/group name to "tomcat/tomcat" and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The solution when I encountered the issue was the declared projection within the raster was not defined in Geoserver. Once the projection parameters are available in the standard Geoserver format (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/configuration/crshandling/customcrs.html) ,

1. In your Geoserver directory and go to data_dir/user_projections
2. In a text editor, open up the epsg.properties file
3. Add a line at the end of the file with the projection parameters