# IMAGEMOSAIC ADD Store -> Could not list layers for this store --> only with some GEOTIFF

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to setup a geotiff folder inside ImageMosaic plugin after following this https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

Using the samples files from the tutorial I'm ok, but if I try to use my own geotiff files I get the following error.

```
2020-02-18 13:17:09,619 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:data/swiss
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:data/swiss and hints 
Hints:
EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@40a0c0f1[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@6cb36f06                                                                                   
System defaults:
LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
FEATURE_FACTORY                  = 
org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@5827af16

at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:170)
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:47)
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.getFilteredItems(GeoServerDataProvider.java:202)
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getFilteredItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:186)
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.size(GeoServerDataProvider.java:220)
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.updateMatched(GeoServerTablePanel.java:597)
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:592)
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:182)
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.<init>(GeoServerTablePanel.java:96)
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$1.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:99)
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.<init>(NewLayerPage.java:98)
at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSuccessfulSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:82)
at org.geoserver.web.data.store.CoverageStoreNewPage.onSave(CoverageStoreNewPage.java:71)
at org.geoserver.web.data.store.AbstractCoverageStorePage$1.onSubmit(AbstractCoverageStorePage.java:139)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1.onSubmit(AjaxSubmitLink.java:111)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior$AjaxFormSubmitter.onSubmit(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:215)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.delegateSubmit(Form.java:1309)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:976)
at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:797)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.form.AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.onEvent(AjaxFormSubmitBehavior.java:171)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155)
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doPost(WicketServlet.java:159)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69)
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66)
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:data/swiss and hints Hints:
EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@40a0c0f1[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
REPOSITORY       = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@6cb36f06                                                                                   
System defaults:
LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true                                                   
FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl                                      
COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8                                                 
GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory                                    
TILE_ENCODING                  = null                                                   
STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl                                       
FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true                                                   
FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http                                                   
FEATURE_FACTORY                  = 
org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@5827af16

at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1558)
at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getGridCoverageReader(ResourcePool.java:1502)
at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl.getGridCoverageReader(CoverageStoreInfoImpl.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:127)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25.getGridCoverageReader(Unknown Source)
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItemsInternal(NewLayerPageProvider.java:86)
... 141 more
```

I think it can be an issue like this about the EPSG [Could not list layers for this store error when creating new ImageMosaic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171284/could-not-list-layers-for-this-store-error-when-creating-new-imagemosaic)

But how can I find the EPSG used by my TIFF files if it is the issue?

I edited this /home/geoserver/data_dir/user_projections/epsg.properties
adding known EPSG of the TIFF country zone, but the error persist.

Comment: You can use https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html

Comment: Obtained this, but I still get the error even after adding it to the custom srs

PROJCS["SWISS_GRID",GEOGCS["SWISS_GRID",DATUM["CH_1903",SPHEROID["BESSEL 1841",6377397.155,299.1528128]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",46.9524055555556],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",7.43958333333333],PARAMETER["azimuth",90],PARAMETER["rectified_grid_angle",90],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",600000],PARAMETER["false_northing",200000],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]

Comment: Any help here? I also tried downloading othet GeoTiff from the web and the only tif working with imagemosaic are the ones included in the tutorial.

Comment: The main error happens here `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create reader from file:data/swiss` but I can't tell why. Add a link to one other GeoTIFF and I can test on my side. What is your GeoServer version and do you use the shapefile index?

Comment: The version is  2.16.2. 
3 sample files in order to test https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3bs4un8ly1w8ulr/AABJpXvrm5y2-fLe1WDZcPCRa?dl=0
I don't use a shapefile index in the folder you will find also my .properties files.

Comment: does tomcat have write permission to the folder where the tiffs are stored?

Comment: yes they are 777 and using another folder with the same permission but with the default files it works.

Comment: @user30184 have you been able to test those files?

Comment: I don't have PostGIS at the moment, so not.